# Need to re-compile or re-establish MPI on Mac OSX. How?

Tags: macos, compilation, fortran, mpi

Recently upgraded my gcc, which includes gfortran, on my Mac OSX.  What I didn't see coming is what happened when I tried to compile an MPI Fortran code a few days later:

```
$> mpif90 aux_procs.f90
aux_procs.f90:3:4:

 use mpi
    1
Fatal Error: Cannot read module file 'mpi.mod' opened at (1), because it was created by a different version of GNU Fortran
compilation terminated.
```

So, as far as I can tell, mpif90 is using the new gfortran, but the MPI "infrastructure", like the MPI module file here, never "got the memo" and was not re-compiled with the new gfortran.  Anyone have any ideas what to do now?  I need to re-compile something or download something new or ... whatever, but I really don't know what to do next.

Comment: How did you install **MPI**? How did you install **gcc**?

Comment: @MarkSetchell   MPI was loaded on the system when I got it, as was a version of gcc.  I updated gcc through mac ports.

Comment: Looks like one for Vladimir...

Comment: you need to rebuild MPI with the new version of the fortran compiler.